# ruby_dep installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, heroku-toolbelt

I'm following the Hartl rails tutorial, figured I'd give ruby a go. Previously was able to deploy to heroku just fine. Started a new project, and right after I changed my gem file and used the "bundle update" command, I got this error message:

```
An error occurred while installing ruby_dep (1.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I tried pushing to my heroku master branch and got this message:

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I updated my bundler, my version of ruby is up to date...no clue what's going on here. Any help?

Comment: try running in `production` mode in local machine and deploy to `heroku`

Comment: Wasn't sure how to run in prod mode so I'm gonna use this https://gist.github.com/averyvery/8d28384543c7680f5b51

Comment: wait, this will only simulate the rails caching, compilation and uglifications. But not the gems you are going to use in production mode. So you simple do `rails s -e production`. This will require you to create database for production mode. `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Karan which ruby version you are using?...please prefer https://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/issues/3

Comment: I got it to work. Restarted the project, updated my ruby version & my bundler. Now I have a new problem - when running 'bundle install', part of the output is 'using Listen 3.1.3. That's great...except when I run 'rails server', I get this message -> 
'Could not find listen-3.1.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.'

Comment: Additionally, I have installed ruby 2.3.0 as required for listen using root permissions. I can't figure out how to ALSO locally install it using current permissions...rbenv global output is 2.3.0-dev, but ruby -v in terminal shows 2.2.0 as the output.

Answer (score 1):

You must either have ruby >= 2.2.5 or add the following gem to your gemfile
gem 'listen', '3.1.1' and then run
 `bundle install`

Since I have ruby 2.2.4, I added the above gem to my gemfile , then ran  bundle install

Everything works fine after this step. Enjoy.

Comment: gem name is incorrect i think .there is no such gem in `rubygems.org`

Comment: This fix works but the gem name is `listen` not `listem`